# saving bytes to xmlfile. invalid Unicode-character

Tags: java, xml, hash

The title pretty much says it.

I calculate a SHA1 Hash for a textfile, so far so good. i write it in an .xml file, by just using a normal FileOutputStream.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out.xml);
fos.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".getBytes());
fos.write("<Digest xmlns=\"http://testnamespace\"".getBytes());
fos.write(getFileHash("C:\\myfile.txt"));
fos.write("</Digest>".getBytes()); 
fos.flush(); 
fos.close();
```

If i now want to parse the xml as DOM, i always get Exceptions like "invalid Unicode-character 0x06, 0x1b", depending on what input file i pass.

What i tried so far:
Different Wrappers for the filestream (eg. PrintWriter)
getBytes("UTF-8");

please tell me how i can save these hashes to xml without facing this

thank you

Comment: I strongly suggest you use an XML library to write XML. You are failing to quote something, I suspect. The library will stop you writing invalid XML. FWIW I use the XOM library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, the `getFileHash` method returns binary data (like a byte[]). However, XML is text so you cannot put arbitrary binary data into it. One way to work around this is to convert the binary data to characters, for example with hex encoding or base64 encoding.

Also, the various `getBytes()` calls will return bytes according to the platform encoding, which may or may not be UTF-8. It is much safer to specify the encoding explicitly.